# StackOverflowError when sending Serializables between activities

Tags: java, android, serialization, stack-overflow

I have two similiar objects, both from the very same class, **they are very identical.**

I would like to pass them **from one activity to another.**

It works most of the time well, but **I got crash reports from a lot of android 4.4 devices** that a particular object **throws StackOverflowError.**

I have checked it out on an Android 4.4 and **I can repeat the error any time.**

I have read that it can be caused by two issue:

- The object is too big
- There is recursion linking in the object

I have logged the two serializable objects with this func:

```
 public static String sizeof(Object obj) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutputStream);

    objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectOutputStream.close();

    return (byteOutputStream.toByteArray().length/1024.f) + " Kbytes";
}
```

I have strange output because the bigger object is working fine 10\10 times and the SMALLER object throws StackOverflowError every time.

---

### The problematic object with crash every time:

> I/BYTE_SIZE: Problematic Object, size: 75.79004 Kbytes

**It causes stack overflow when I try to pass it between activites using Intents with serialization:**

03-15 13:59:18.492 6132-6132/hu.adam.myapp.pack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

> Process: hu.adam.myapp.pack, PID: 6132
>       java.lang.StackOverflowError
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkReadPrimitiveTypes(ObjectInputStream.java:394)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:745)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>           at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1023)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1115)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1244)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1833)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStre

---

### A MUCH bigger object without any problem or crash, it works every time 10/10

> I/BYTE_SIZE: Large Object, size: 188.49121 Kbytes

**So my questions:**

**If it is not size related - it must be the recursion related error** - but ho do I find it out precisely? As far as I know I don't use any circular linking, the Object is like a pyramid hierarchy - but of course I could be wrong.

Any advice where should I start searching or how should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you also list the two object class definitions.